# Linker not linking external source library

Tags: c++, visual-studio

So I have a project located at "C:/something/something/project.sln"

The functions I am using in this project I am wanting to use again over and over again. So I have created

"C:/folder/include.h", "C:/folder/maths/maths.h", "C:/folder/maths/maths.cpp"

Include.h:

```
#include #pragma once

#include "maths\maths.h"
```

maths.h

```
namespace maths
{
   int add(int a, int b);
}
```

maths.cpp

```
#include "maths.h"
namespace maths
{
  int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
}
```

function 'add' is unresolved external.

I am using VS2017. I am guessing it is to do with using the linker or additional include directories however, nothing I tried there got it to work. 
I suppose I could create a project in 'folder' then compile as .lib, however, I don't think that, that should be needed. Thanks :)

Comment: You just need to add *both* .cpp files to your project, that's all.

Comment: Did you add the library to the project, where you want to use it?

Comment: @NuPagadi I think OP misuses the word "library".

Comment: @NuPagadi so I do need to create a .lib file for /library? 
Create new lib then add source from /folder compile then include? 
Thanks

Comment: @HolyBlackCat you are right sorry for confusion.

Comment: That's not a *source library*. It's a source **file**. There is a major difference between them.

Comment: No, you don't need to create a library. You could, but it'll just make things harder. As I said, you need to add `maths.cpp` to the project.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That you very much :)